# Bitcoin core wallet transactions and synchronisation

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, wallet, synchronization

I have Bitcoin Core wallet.

I wanted to know if each transaction I need sync the wallet?

(I have a new business that accept bitcoin and I must to save each transaction)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With Bitcoin Core you'll run a full node. So, for every transaction someone does to your business, your Bitcoin Core wallet need to be synchronized with the complete blockchain.

Comment: So each transaction i must sync manually ?

Comment: No, you just have to make sure you are synchronized with the head of the blockchain. When deciding if a payment is finalized you should look at the number of block confirmations. Three usually is enough.

Comment: One more question please to close my case . **ill explain the steps i want figure out.** For example i have an empty bitcoin core wallet . Step 1. l backup the wallet and go offline. Step 2. someone send me a bitcoin to this wallet and i can see it(in balance).  Step 3 .ill restore my bitcoin core wallet to the initial point.. **What will happen then ?**

Comment: I assume that with restore the wallet you start over with the blockchain from scratch. What will happen is that initially the balance will be 0 since your node is not yet aware of the transaction. So you will need to synchronize up to the block where the transaction was included (this will take some time). At that time the balance will be updated. After that the synchronization will continue until it's up-to-date with the head.

Comment: i assumed the same , but  tried to avoid making test this week because lake of time.  Thanks anyway , will update after testing if its working as you mentioned above. THANKS!

Answer (score 2):

When you create a transaction, the transaction is broadcast to other Bitcoin nodes and reaches miners.

When a miner includes your transaction in a block that they successfully mine, they broadcast the block that contains your transaction - this is the first confirmation. When other blocks get mined on top of that block, those are additional confirmations of your transaction.

When you run Bitcoin core on your PC it will try to synchronise your local copy of the blockchain. It needs to get the latest blocks to add to your local copy of the blockchain so that it can find out whether your transaction got confirmed.

Comment: got you friend. thanks for the detailed answer. So actually i need to sync my wallet each transaction ?

Comment: Can you please check out my response to previous commenter ?

Comment: @Sadikov: Hello, you are new and may not know that comments are for clarifying questions or answers and are disposable. It is better to ask a new question using the "Ask Question" link above and include a link to this question if needed. That way people with the same question can find it's answers using Google or this site's search bar without having to scan through all the comments (which may get deleted in a clean up - they are temporary/disposable, Qs and A's are not)